# EasyMock and generic params

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock, jersey-client

I'm trying to get to grips with EasyMock to mock some calls to Jersey client APIs... 
I'm trying to mock a call to the following call Builder API:

```
<T> T post(Entity<?> entity, Class<T> responseType);
```

doing the following:

```
 EasyMock.expect(mockInvocationBuilder.post(Entity.json(request), Response.class)).andReturn(mockResponse).anyTimes();
```

this is giving me the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call Builder.post(Entity{entity=com.ibm.apin.apim.request.CreateOrgRequest@936a7073, variant=Variant[mediaType=application/json, language=null, encoding=null], annotations=[]}, class javax.ws.rs.core.Response):
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here and how I can mock this correctly?

Comment: By default, EasyMock matches the parameters using `equals`. Is there a suitable `equals` method defined on `Entity`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [EasyMock User Guide](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#verification-expectations):

> To match an actual method call on the Mock Object with an expectation, `Object` arguments are by default compared with `equals()`.

You have to override [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), use a built-in argument matcher (like [`EasyMock#anyObject`](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#anyObject-java.lang.Class-)), write your own [`IArgumentMatcher`](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/IArgumentMatcher.html) or use a [`Capture`](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/Capture.html).